# Can 'emotional' be related to 'happy'?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

[*The Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/emotional#:%7E:text=connected%20with%20or%20showing%20feelings) says that 'emotional' has such a meaning:

> connected with or showing feelings.

Actually, all of the 'emotional's with that meaning I encountered have meanings somewhat related to 'sad'.

For examples:

- In *The Cambridge Dictionary* page mentioned above:

  > The mayor made an emotional appeal for aid following the tornado.

  Unless the mayor wants to lose his/her power, the emotional appeal here is obviously a sad one.
- In [*The Free Dictionary*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/emotional#:%7E:text=or%20exhibiting%20emotion%3A-,an%20emotional%20farewell,-.):

  > an emotional farewell.

  I don't think it appropriate to be happy at a farewell.
- When you google 'emotional movies', the contents in the first page are all about sad movies.
- In the wiki article about '[Scene (performing arts)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_(performing_arts)#:%7E:text=Because%20of%20their%20frequent%20appearance%20in%20films%2C%20some%20types%20of%20scenes%20have%20acquired%20names%2C%20such%20as%20love%20scene%2C%20sex%20scene%2C%20nude%20scene%2C%20dream%20scene%2C%20action%20scene%2C%20car%20chase%20scene%2C%20crash%20scene%2C%20emotional%20scene%2C%20fight%20scene%2C%20tragedy%20scene%2C%20or%20post%2Dcredits%20scene.)', there's such a sentence:

  > Because of their frequent appearance in films, some types of scenes have acquired names, such as love scene, sex scene, nude scene, dream scene, action scene, car chase scene, crash scene, **emotional scene**, fight scene, tragedy scene, or post-credits scene.

I tried to check the corresponding meaning of 'emotional' in other dictionaries. The related explanations of 'emotional' in [*The Free Dictionary*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/emotional) are

- > Arousing or intended to arouse the emotions.
- > Marked by or exhibiting emotion.

[The Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emotional#:%7E:text=appealing%20to%20or%20arousing%20emotion) also kicks the can down to the meaning of 'emotion':

> appealing to or arousing emotion.

However, according to [*The Free Dictionary*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/emotion#:%7E:text=any%20strong%20feeling%2C%20as%20of%20joy%2C%20sorrow%2C%20or%20fear), 'emotion' means

> any strong feeling, as of joy, sorrow, or fear.

As is clearly stated here, 'emotion' does not necessarily imply sadness. Then, why is 'emotional' often related to 'sad'? Can 'emotional' be related to 'happy'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, emotional can be happy.
An emotional reunion might be happy, even if it's tearful.
There might be an emotional celebration after a victory.

Comment: Nice! But I can image people crying on the situations of your examples. Is there a situation with no tears but all laughs that can be described by 'emotional'?

Comment: Yes, for example, a scene of team players lifting up and carrying one of their members after a victory, maybe accompanied by the cheers of their fans.